# Choosing LDO to power ESP8266 on lithium battery

Tags: microcontroller, datasheet, low-power, battery-operated, ldo

I want to power ESP8266 on lithium battery with a PIR sensor and have a small solar module to charge the battery, there is also weird looking 3pin transparent light sensor that by guess testing I found that at 3.3V it drivers OUT-Pin High linearly so when there is light ESP8266 goes deepsleep waking up every 10min.

My total power consumption is:

- **PIR sensor: `1mA` to `2mA`**
- **Light sensor: `1mA` to `2mA`**
- **ESP8266 (onboard AMS1117): `2mA deepsleep`, `17mA ON` and `70mA sending push notification over Wi-Fi`**

**Solar Module provides 6V 50mA Max**

So during day light: `3mA` to `5mA`,

During night `20mA` normally and `75mA` for 3 to 5 seconds to push notification when something is detected then back to normal

Now to power my motion detection setup on battery, I need external LDO to power my setup because:

- *AMS1117 cannot output 3.3V from a Single Lithium Battery*
- *AMS1117 has high dropout, cannot utilize full capacity of battery*
- *ESP8266 might crash below 2.5V*
- *PIR sensor fails below 3.3V*
- *Light sensor fails below 3V*

Now I have 4 choices for an LDO that I can have shipped to me without waiting entire month:

1. **XC6206P332MR**
2. **MIC5219**
3. **HT7333**
4. **RT9193**

I spent many hours trying to decide between them but I am not that good at reading datasheets, all of them appear to have capabilities for my scenario but there might be strong spikes during WiFi operations and there might be rainy days with no sunlight and I need my system to perform for at least 3days and nights without charge at 1000mAh 18650 Lithium battery with best performance and lowest quiescent current.

**UPDATE:** Placed an order for TD6817 synchronous buck regulator (as it was only one immediately available) after discussion in comments.

Comment: The XC6206P332MR seems to have the lowest dropout voltage of the bunch, but these are all small SMD packages so heat dissipation will be important as well. You really should get an all-in-one power management IC with MPPT tracking, battery charging, and buck/boost output capability but they may not be available to you in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: buck-boost are not suitable for microcontrollers, battery protection + simple diode from solar appear to be most power efficient solution to me @vir

Comment: @asim In what way are buck-boost converters not suitable for microcontrollers?

Comment: I think you're confusing units here. mAh is current × time; you want to specify current!

Comment: @JohnD switching noise can cause deep sleep/wake issues, noise can cause PIR sensor to false trigger

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for pointing out, fixed it

Comment: @asim um, "switching noise can cause deep sleep/wake issues," that seems totally made up for any reasonably designed buck/boost converter. (you'll find that in real applications, having your microcontroller on a buck is *very* common. You'll find that almost all modern computers, smartphones, … rely on that.)"noise can cause PIR sensor to false trigger": You'll have to sensibly filter the supply voltage then. Again, this sounds like a problem that doesn't exist with modern switch-mode supply.

Comment: You can either suggest me some or I can start desoldering LEDs from the ones in my drawer to test them, I am willing to sacrifice one mA than to get a false notification of motion detection, even wifi turning on can cause false trigger, gets worse on smps but is otherwise very stable, also filterering output further complicates things for me @MarcusMüller

Comment: @asim no, your insistence on linear regulators is what complicates the situation. Your noise problems are not based on facts.

Comment: @MarcusMüller my choices for switch mode regulators are: xl6009, lm2596, xl4015 and mp2307,none support input below 4.5v and tested to cause failures during wakeup and false triggers on PIR, only mt3608 have 2v min input which is boost only, then some smps have LEDs, not available at local stores or might take up to a month to arrive

Comment: The LM2596 is *ancient*, by far not a modern converter, the others seem mostly to be clones of other old chips, and as you notice, none of them do what you need. So, that is not a sensible choice of components, just as your selection of linear regulators is not a sensible choice of components. Modern buck-boost regulators use the same quiescent current as e.g. the MIC5219, need the same amount of external components, and are pretty readily available. I of course can't solve your supply problems, nor do I intend to, but for example, mouser.com has the TPS631000 in stock, some 11,000 pieces

Comment: https://octopart.com/search?q=TPS631000&currency=EUR&specs=0&sort=median_price_1000&sort-dir=asc

Comment: I completely agree with @MarcusMüller, a well-designed modern switching converter is perfectly appropriate for running a microcontroller.  It's done all the time.  Boost, buck-boost or buck are all appropriate depending on the system requirements.